# Moving from Product Manager Approach to Brand Manager Approach- how?

Tags: standards, branding, product-management, strategy

Working with a relatively immature cX company but they have aspirations and executive buy in. They know need to shift their product managers from thinking beyond just the product to the overall experience and brand. WOndering if anyone has case studies/ tools on how to move the thinking and approach from a "how do I sell this product..." to a "how do I use this product to provide a great experience and reinforce our brand aspirations?"

Any case studies or tips? Really looking for the how they did it...

Cheers.

Comment: How many products does this company manage under its brand?

Answer (score 2):

### Brand and content strategy both need to be considered, and both are related to UX, and will help to unify product experiences.

Brand manager positions can have fairly large differences in responsibilities depending on the size of the organization. From your description, it sounds like you need to unify the product experiences from their individual silos. This may be one role, or several. Either way, you'll have to consider a couple things to promote shared understanding across the company:

#### Brand as unifying look and feel: have visual standards.

as @jhurley mentioned, you need clear brand standards, by this I mean primarily visual standards.

Mailchimp is thorough on this (NOTE: I don't work for Mailchimp; I have just had great experiences as a customer).

Even though this is the presentation layer, they consider this part of the UX (some companies silo their visual designers a bit); it's even in the URL: [https://ux.mailchimp.com/](https://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns/typography)

[image]

#### Content strategy as unifying voice and tone: have a content styleguide.

*How we speak to customers and prospects* is the concern here. Once again, [Mailchimp](http://styleguide.mailchimp.com/) considers this part of the UX; they do a brilliant job across their company.

Here's a screenshot showing all the considerations they touch on. If you're trying to unify your product experiences, shared language and tone is essential. It puts both product and communications teams on the same page.

This will help unify the personality that we **as one company** address our prospects and our users. Are we quirky? conservative? playful? serious?
This will effect everything from error messages to emails to sales pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stewart - it sounds like you need a great Brand Standards Guide. More than just a Style Guide, a Brand Standards Guide expands beyond corporate fonts, colors, and graphics. A great Brand Standards Guide should be effective and self explanatory in the hands of any employee. This playbook should answer any question and give perspective on how everybody fit into the company (including customers) AS WELL AS bring unique talents to help grow.

If this is the case, and your question is, "where can I find a great Brand Standard PDF to emmulate?" -- the answer is going to cost a lot. No two Brand Standards should be alike. Just like each company should have Unique Positioning Statements -- each company should have a well researched, custom-written, Brand Standards Guide.

Does your company have access to a marketing/branding agency? Do you already have a Brand Standards that may need to be dusted off and re-written? Does you think a Brand Standards Guide is the answer to your problem?